# Dropdownlist selected item validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Hello i am trying to validate dropdownlist as it should not have selected item as "--- Pick One ---" by using compare validator but it's not working. Please can any one guide me. It will be very helpful for me.

My code is :-

```
enter code here

<asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwn_ImDiv" CssClass="inner-dropdown1"   runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="Division" DataValueField="Division" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
<asp:ListItem>--- Pick One ---</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" ControlToValidate="drpdwn_ImDiv" Type="String" ValueToCompare="--- Pick One ---" CssClass="validator" Font-Size="10px" Operator="NotEqual" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator"></asp:CompareValidator>`
```

Comment: Is Value of first item in dropdown is "Select"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwn_ImDiv" CssClass="inner-dropdown1"   runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" DataTextField="Division" DataValueField="Division" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
<asp:ListItem>--- Pick One ---</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
 ErrorMessage="Please select" ControlToValidate="drpdwn_ImDiv" 
InitialValue="--- Pick One ---"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. @MiteshGadhiya

Comment: Welcome my friend...:)

Answer (score 0):

Start by using a `Text` and `Value` property for a ListItem. Then you can use a RequiredFieldValidator to check the empty value of the first ListItem.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwn_ImDiv" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--- Pick One ---" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="drpdwn_ImDiv"
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```